# app.get('/try', function (req, res) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am new to node and express. this is my code :

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();  
app.get('/', function (req, res)
{ res.send(' { “Hello”: “World” }'); }); 
app.get('/about', function (req, res){ 
 res.send(' { “Hello”: “World” }'); });    
app.listen(3000);
```

this works but when i try

```
app.get('/try', function (req, res){
res.send(' { “Hello”: “World” }');
});
```

the browser give me this message: Cannot GET /try

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

this is express 4 version

Comment: So you're saying the only thing you've changed is the path, as in from `/about` to `/try`, and it doesn't work? Nothing else has changed, the route is in the same place, there are no errors etc

Comment: Could you show us what the code looks like, after you've tried to add the ```/try``` path?

Comment: And what URL you're accessing.

Comment: Unrelated side note: if you want to send JSON, use `res.json()` instead. The  double quotes are messed up although it shouldn't cause the request to fail.

Comment: Just a wild guess... maybe you did not restart your server after adding the new route?

Comment: Thank you Migg.. I restarted the server and it worked. Thank You.

Comment: JS compiles the code and keeps it in memory, so just changing a file will not  do anything. You should have a look at gulp or grunt and their express server and watch tasks. So that whenever you save a file your server gets an automatic restart. You can also do this by using forever or pm2 with watch options, or some IDEs support it internally like WebStorm.

Comment: i just installed pm2 and restarted the server. this is the error message i got.Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1236:14)
    at listen (net.js:1272:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1368:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/Users/EthosOneStudios/Desktop/exp_wk4/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Express server solved the issue